# Invert yAxis using NVD3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, nvd3.js

So I finally was able to set the yAxis tickValues but now when I use yRange() to inverse it the ticks disappear, is there a better way of doing this? Or is there another setting I'm forgetting to add??

I'm also setting the xAxis tickValues, I need them to be evenly spaced like in an ordinal scale. But I read you're not supposed to change the scale type using nvd3 charts.

Here's the relevant code:

```
var xLabels = ["", 250, 500, 750, 1000, 1500, 2000, 3000, 4000, 6000, 8000, 10000];
var yLabels = [-10, 0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100, 110, 120];
var chart = nv.models.lineChart()
    .x(function (d) {
        return d.Hz;
    })
    .y(function (d) {
        return d.dB;
    })
    .showLegend(false)
    .showYAxis(true)
    .showXAxis(true);
chart.forceY(yLabels);
chart.forceX(xLabels);
chart.yRange([0, 450]); //This inverts the yAxis

chart.xAxis
    .axisLabel('Frequency (Hz)')
    .tickValues(xLabels)
    .orient('top'); //reposition xaxis labels on top

chart.yAxis
    .axisLabel('dB')
    .tickValues(yLabels);
```

Answer (score 0):

If the above code is part of an `addGraph()` function, maybe try adding `nv.utils.windowResize(chart.update);` before returning the `chart` object.

Comment: Any chance you could drop that function, an svg element and a sample dataset into a JSFiddle so we can see what's happening?

Comment: I can't seem to get it working, but here's the basic setup: https://jsfiddle.net/xecba6mn/

Comment: Here's a link to my post in Github, there's a picture of what I'm trying to build. https://github.com/nvd3-community/nvd3/issues/99